# How to import a Unsigned Long (ULONG64) into x64 ASM File in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit, masm64

OK so I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 with MASM enabled and I'm trying to declare a variable in my ASM file that is defined outside of the .ASM file but in the same project. How can I do this ?

I've tried the following:

```
EXTERN MyVar:ULONG64
```

but Visual Studio gives me the following compile error:

```
Error   A2006   undefined symbol : ULONG64  TestDrv C:\Users\XFL\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\XFL\TestDrv\TestDrv\SwapSrc.asm  9
```

Comment: ULONG64 isn't a native type.  Do you have a typedef for it or an include that defines it?  Does `unsigned long long` work any better?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd thank you. My apologies for not being clear but I'm declaring the above statement in a ASM file that is part of the VS project. I did try unsigned long long but it gave me a different error Error A2008 syntax error : long TestDrv C:\Users\XFL\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\XFL\TestDrv\TestDrv\HookSwapSrc.asm 9

Comment: So how about `QWORD`?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd thank you. I cannot declare this variable as type QWORD in my .cpp file since I cannot use the QWORD identifier in x64 bit mode the compiler gives me an error. Error (active) E0020 identifier "QWORD" is undefined TestDrv C:\Users\XFL\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\XFL\TestDrv\TestDrv\HookSprw.cpp 22

Comment: Does `unsigned long long` work any better?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd thank you. I did try "unsigned long long" but I still get an error 
Error A2008 syntax error : long

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/qword?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0):

C and assembler are very different languages and everything is spelled differently.
Assembler names all 64 bit types (including floating point doubles) QWORD, the C language and Windows headers use other names such as __int64, long long, etc.

Similarly assembler writes hexadecimal 64 bit numbers as 0123456789ABCDEFh while the C language writes it 0x0123456789ABCDEFui64 etc. etc.